# ¿Como puedo obtener la información que he guardado en una estructura dentro de un archivo binario por medio de c?

Tags: c, archivo

Tengo que hacer un archivo de tamaño fijo el cual lo defino con un arreglo de caracteres char relleno[1024] con lo que cada posicion tiene el caracter '\0' y asi logro definir el tamaño pero dentro de este tengo dos estructuras una al inicio y otra en medio de la misma, cuando leo la que esta al inicio logro recuperar la informacion pero la que se encuentra en el medio me posiciono con fseek en donde lo he escrito y lo que encuentro es unicamente los 0's con los que rellene...
aqui el codigo

```
    //EBR que ingresamos inicialmente

           Ext extend;
           extend.part_status=0;
           strcpy(extend.part_name,"prueba 2.0");
           extend.part_start=x;

           FILE *texto;
           texto=fopen(leer_arch,"w+b");
           if(texto){

        //escribimos el MBR
               fwrite(&mbr_init, sizeof(Disco),1,texto);

           fseek(texto,sizeof(mbr_init) ,SEEK_SET);
           int nuevotam=(x-sizeof(mbr_init))/1024;
           int i;
           for(i=0;i<nuevotam;i++){                

        //Rellenamos antes del EBR
               fwrite(&relleno,sizeof(relleno),1,texto);
           }

    //nos movemos x bytes para luego escribir el EBR        
           fseek(texto,x,SEEK_SET);
           fwrite(&extend, sizeof(Ext),1,texto);


           int tamanito=x+extend.part_size;
           nuevotam=(tam-tamanito)/1024;

    //terminamos de rellenar el disco
           for(i=0;i<nuevotam  ;i++){

               fwrite(&relleno,sizeof(relleno),1,texto);

           }
           fclose(texto);
                //Tratamos de recuperar nuestro EBR para verificar que es >>accesible        FILE *texto2;
           Ext prueb;
           texto2=fopen(leer_arch,"w+b");
           if(texto2){

           fseek(texto2,x,SEEK_SET);
           int prueba = fread(&prueb, sizeof(Ext),1,texto2);
           printf(prueb.part_name);


           }
```

Creo que mi problema es al momento de posicionarme pero es exactemente el mismo numero que uso al escribirlo el que uso para leerlo

Answer (score 0):

El último [fopen()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm), está siendo llamado en modo write, `"w"`.

> write: Create an empty file for output operations. **If a file with
>   the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file
>   is treated as a new empty file**.